Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check
I'm facing a npm vulnerability and I don't know how to fix it.
"Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check".

I googled it and asked it from ChatGPT and it gave a suggestion to downgrade react-scripts to 3.1.0 but that ended of having 80 vulnerabilities instead of a solution so please someone tell me about this

Have you seen this Stack Overflow Q&A: github Dependabot alert: Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check?

Hi may I know if you have resolved this issue? I am trying to use web3 in react but getting the same vulnerability when using ``npm install web3''. Thanks in advance if you could tell me on any updates!
